# Derivatives not holding their definition when generated with a function

Tags: function-construction, image-processing

I'm trying to create a method to generate the function and the partial derivatives of an image.
The problem is that, when executed, the derivatives won't hold their definitions.

As I see it, **dI1x, dI1y, dI2x, dI2y** aren't functions. **I1 and I2** have no problem at being evaluated with any value of **x** and **y** whereas, in this example, **dI1x** when evaluated appears this way **dI1x[1, 2]**.

Thanks for your time, I'm really lost. Any hint would be appreciated.

If any more information needed, I'm at your service!

```
(* imgen input: ibigsize, isize, scale *)
(* imgen output: {{Functions}, {images}} *)

imgen[ibigsize_, isize_, scale_, a_] := Block[
   {ibighalf, ihalf, i1big0, r1, r2, i1big, i2big, i1dim, i2dim, i1, 
    i2, I1, I2, dI1x, dI1y, dI2x, dI2y}, (
    
    ibighalf = Ceiling[N[ibigsize/2]];
    ihalf = Ceiling[N[isize/2]];
    
    i1big0 = Blur[RandomImage[{0 - 0.75, 1 + 0.75}, ibigsize], 3];
    
    (* Rotation Transform, center *)
    r1 = N[RotationTransform[0 \[Degree]]];
    r2 = N[
      TranslationTransform[{ibighalf[[1]], ibighalf[[2]]}] . 
       RotationTransform[a \[Degree]] . 
       TranslationTransform[-{ibighalf[[1]], ibighalf[[2]]}]];
    
    i1big = 
     ImageTransformation[i1big0, r1, DataRange -> Full, 
      Resampling -> "Cubic", Padding -> "Reflected"];
    i2big = 
     ImageTransformation[i1big0, r2, DataRange -> Full, 
      Resampling -> "Cubic", Padding -> "Reflected"];
    
    i1 = ImageTake[i1big,
      {ibighalf[[1]] - ihalf[[1]], 
       ibighalf[[1]] + ihalf[[1]]}, {ibighalf[[2]] - ihalf[[2]], 
       ibighalf[[2]] + ihalf[[2]]}];
    i2 = ImageTake[i2big,
      {ibighalf[[1]] - ihalf[[1]], 
       ibighalf[[1]] + ihalf[[1]]}, {ibighalf[[2]] - ihalf[[2]], 
       ibighalf[[2]] + ihalf[[2]]}];
    
    i1dim = ImageDimensions[i1];
    i2dim = ImageDimensions[i2];
    
    i1 = ImageResize[i1, scale*{i1dim[[1]], i1dim[[2]]}];
    i2 = ImageResize[i2, scale*{i2dim[[1]], i2dim[[2]]}];
    
    I1 = ListInterpolation[Transpose[ImageData[i1]], 
      Method -> "Spline", InterpolationOrder -> 3];
    I2 = ListInterpolation[Transpose[ImageData[i2]], 
      Method -> "Spline", InterpolationOrder -> 3];
    
    (* First Derivatives *)
    
    dI1x[x_, y_] := D[I1[x, y], x];
    dI1y[x_, y_] := D[I1[x, y], y];
    dI2x[x_, y_] := D[I2[x, y], x];
    dI2y[x_, y_] := D[I2[x, y], y];
    
    {{I1, I2, dI1x, dI1y, dI2x, dI2y}, {i1, i2}}
    
    )];
```

This are the results i get when i run the function **imgen**:

```
ibigsize = {99, 99};
isize = {20, 20};

Idata = imgen[ibigsize, isize, 1, 1];
Ifunctions = Idata[[1]]; (*{I1, I2, dI1x, dI1y, dI2x, dI2y}*)
im = Idata[[2]]; (*{i1, i2}*)

Ifunctions
Ifunctions[[1]][1, 2]
Ifunctions[[3]][1, 2]
idim

(* out *)

{Interpolatingfunction[], Interpolatingfunction[], dI1x, dI1y, dI2x, dI2y}
0.452859
dI1x[1, 2]
{21, 21}
```

Comment: Have you already seen `DerivativeFilter[]`?

Comment: I hadn't, but will take a look! The issue is that I need a continuous function to work within the next steps. Maybe I could get this, and then interpolate a function for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the derivatives as pure functions, like:

```
dI1x := Derivative[1, 0][I1];
dI1y = Derivative[0, 1][I1];
dI2x := Derivative[1, 0][I2];
dI2y := Derivative[0, 1][I2];
```

Then e.g.:

```
SeedRandom[1];
ibigsize = {99, 99};
isize = {20, 20};
Idata = imgen[ibigsize, isize, 1, 1];

Idata[[1, 3]][1, 1]

(*-0.123381*)
```

Comment: Thanks! this worked :)